# Change DOM element CSS with jquery Not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two clickable headings. When you click one, it changes blue. If you click the other one, it changes blue, but should "unclick" the other heading and change it back to black.

I'm trying to do this using jquery `not`...

```
$("#pal1, #pal2").click(function(event) {
    $(this).css({"color" : "blue"});
    var pal1 = $(this).attr('id');
    var pal2 = $(this).next().attr('id');   
    $(this).not(pal2).css({"color" : "black"}); //if the selected heading is not pal1, or not pal2, changed the one that is not == $(this) back to black.
});
```

Or something like that.

---

Edit: I know I can do it this way... but wanted to use jQuery functions to reduce code size. Plus this isn't very efficient.

```
$("#pal1, #pal2").click(function(event) {
    $(this).css({"color" : "blue"});        
    if ($(this).attr('id') !== $("#pal1").attr('id')) {
        $("#pal1").css({"color" : "black"});
    }
    else {
        $("#pal2").css({"color" : "black"});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set both to `black`, then set the clicked one to `blue`.

```
$("#pal1, #pal2").click(function(event) {
  $("#pal1, #pal2").css({"color" : "black"});
  $(this).css({"color" : "blue"});
});
```

Comment: lol crap... I guess that would be the best way to go. I guess I was just trying too hard to implement other jQuery functions

Comment: Beat me to it :) Here is a fiddle using this technique http://jsfiddle.net/23Mk5/ It also stores the elements in a variable to prevent duplication, and uses classes instead of applying the style directly.